# Trouble searching for posts about python's with statement

Tags: support, tags, search

Today I am trying to search for SO some questions and answers about python's `with` statement (see [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)).  To my surprise, searching for:

[python with](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20with)

returned zero matches, and searching for:

[with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=with%20statement)

returned a whole lot of irrelevant results about if statements, for statements, etc.   Are my search terms being post-processed?  I was able to find some relevant results further down the list in a search for [[python] +with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20%2bwith%20statement), but they aren't really being prioritised properly.

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

There's a [with-statement](/questions/tagged/with-statement) tag. Search for that and [python](/questions/tagged/python) by entering:

```
[python] [with-statement]
```

in the search box, and you will get relevant posts.

Comment: Thanks, it only returns 3 results though.  There are several useful posts about python's with statement that aren't tagged (yet), so is there any way to force 'with' to be included in the search terms?

Comment: I'm getting 39 results. Of course, this will only match questions that were tagged as such. There's always google `+with +statement +python site:stackoverflow.com`